# Can't install node js on mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation

After node installation on mac, regular installation is finished properly but it can't be found on terminal.

I used this line to define the PATH : `export PATH=/usr/local/bin: $PATH`
and it still can't find node or npm on terminal.

Comment: How did you install node?

Comment: nodejs.org then the install button, downloaded the .pkg  and thats it. show in the end that it installed ok

Answer (score 0):

What is your `echo $PATH` output? Make sure you use correct syntax like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin